# Binding WPF ListView to Dictionary<string, int> only updates on the first change

Tags: c#, wpf, dictionary, binding

I have bound my ListView to a Dictionary but it is only updating for the first time i add something to the Dictionary. Any subsequent changes don't get updated.

WPF:

```
<ListView Name="LogLevelListView" ItemsSource="{Binding MyDictionary, Mode=TwoWay}" >
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Name" Width="Auto" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Key}" />
            <GridViewColumn Header="Level" Width="Auto" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Value}" />
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

C# Code:

```
MyDictionary.Add(MyKey, MyValue);
OnPropertyChanged("MyDictionary");
```

Any idea why only the first update works?

Comment: @CathaIMF does my answer works for your issue?

Comment: @JuanM.Elosegui - I haven't gotten around to implementing it yet to see. I did what user3690202 suggested as a workaround which is working for the moment. Once i get around to implementing it properly i will come back and mark your answer as correct.

Answer (score 2):

You should use a collection that implements `INotifyCollectionChanged` for instance [ObservableCollection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Represents a dynamic data collection that provides notifications when
>   items get added, removed, or when the whole list is refreshed.

**Update**

If you use the binding in that way your collection will not update due to the way `ItemsControl.ItemsSource` it is implemented.

Go to [here](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/Controls/ItemCollection.cs,86cba902d9de238c) line 1687 and you will see something like:

```
if (_collectionView == view)
      return;
```

Your collection reference is the same, hence it will never refresh.

*That is why it only works the first update.*

Comment: Maybe, but binding to a dictionary like this should work.

Comment: I agree with the use of ObservableCollection. I kind of wish WPF had a built-in ObservableDictionary. @CathalMF - you might be able to get around the limitation Juan is talking about by setting the binding to null, then setting it back to the dictionary, whenever you change something.

Comment: @user3690202 Yes resetting the ItemSource to null and back did the trick. But i guess i should implement an observable collection.

Comment: @CathalMF - yes, ObservableCollection is probably the only collection you need to know about in WPF MVVM :)

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at [ObservableDictionary implementionation by Dr. WPF](http://drwpf.com/blog/2007/09/16/can-i-bind-my-itemscontrol-to-a-dictionary/).

Comment: ListCollectionView doesnt take a dictionary in the constructor